# Best way to understand whats going in assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

To chalenge my self I'm trying to learn assemble.  Using IDA I found this function:

```
Question - (void)setCorrectAnswerIndex:(int)

; void __cdecl -[Question setCorrectAnswerIndex:](struct Question *self, SEL, int)
__Question_setCorrectAnswerIndex__
MOV             R1, #(_OBJC_IVAR_$_Question.correctAnswerIndex - 0x5C750) ; int correctAnswerIndex;
ADD             R1, PC  ; int correctAnswerIndex;
LDR             R1, [R1] ; int correctAnswerIndex;
STR             R2, [R0,R1]
BX              LR
; End of function -[Question setCorrectAnswerIndex:]
```

I'm just having a hard time figuring out how it works and how could I modify it. so setCorrectAnswerIndex will always set to a static number or something.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see why looking at compiled high-level code isn't a great way to learn. From an ARM assembly point of view what's going on is this:

- Move a constant into register R1
- Add the current Program Counter to that to create the address of a relative offset from this code into some other part of the program image
- Load whatever value was stored at that address into R1
- Store the value held in R2 to the address made by R0 + R1
- Return to the caller by branching to the address held in the Link Register

What does that mean in the context of whatever program this is? *I have no idea*. I don't know what language it was compiled from, so I don't know how the parameters are passed*. I don't know the structure and layout of things (which depend on both the language and the individual program) so I don't know what those offsets and pointers point to. Saying what this assembly code *does* gets nowhere near to saying what it *achieves*. What if this function actually does something unrelated to answer indices and just has a really misleading name?

In short, if you want to [learn assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270078/how-should-i-learn-arm-assembly), [learn assembly](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0013c/index.html).

If you want to learn reverse engineering, [learn assembly](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ARM+assembly+tutorial). *Then*, armed with that knowledge, start the very much harder task of learning reverse engineering.

Here's a tip: the only side-effect of this function is to store R2 somewhere. You can't patch out any of the preceding instructions without breaking everything, so getting a different value into R2 before it's written is rather difficult. Maybe there's room at the call site? Patching out the return with a relative branch to somewhere nearby where there's room to patch in more code, reusing R0 and R1 to write a new value then returning to the original LR would be my thought.

<sub>* yes, I'm playing dumb a bit here. I'm guessing it's Objective-C, which is *probably* using the ARM EABI but I don't feel like looking it up to confirm. Besides, the thought of going anywhere near anything to do with XCode ever again makes me shudder.</sub>